# List Of - are items by reference or value

Tags: vb.net, list, types, reference

I am using VB.net. I created a List Of datatables that were populated. At that point the list contains the populated datatables. Later I cleared the datatables. At that point the datatables were cleared in the list also. I then repopulated the datatables but the datatables in the list were still empty. So I am confused. Are the datatables in the list a reference or are they copies?

```
Dim listOfDatatables As New List(Of Datatable)
listIOfDatatables.Add(dt1)
listOfDatatablles.Add(dt2)
<at this point the list contains populated datatables>
dt1.Clear()
dt2.Clear()
<at this point the list contains empty datatables>
<now I repopulate the datatables but the list still contains empty datatables>
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: How about showing us how you are filling them. Did you know a `DataSet` was designed to hold `DataTables`?